# Alternative to using subqueries in SQL statements?

Tags: sql, query-optimization, subquery

I have two tables:

```
TableA: (a temporary table)
ItemId (int)

TableB:
ItemId (int), ParentID (int)
```

I want to retrieve all items in Table A where the ParentID of any of the items in Table A doesn't exist as an ItemID. (i.e. I want to get the root of the items in TableA)

This query does what I want:

```
SELECT a.ItemID
FROM TableA a
INNER JOIN TableB b ON a.ItemId = b.ItemID
WHERE b.ParentID NOT IN ( SELECT * from TableA )
```

as does this one:

```
SELECT b.ItemID 
FROM TableB b
WHERE b.ItemID IN ( SELECT * FROM TableA)
AND b.ParentID NOT IN ( SELECT * FROM TableA )
```

I am not satisfied with either of the queries, particularly because of the use of NOT IN/IN. Is there a way to do this without them? Perhaps a cleaner way that doesn't require subqueries?

Sample Data:

```
Table A
-------
2
3
5
6

Table B
--------
1 | NULL
2 | 1
3 | 1
4 | 3
5 | 3
6 | 3
```

Desired Result:

```
2
3
```

Thanks

Comment: Is there a reason you are against these subqueries?  They should run faster than a `LEFT JOIN` in this instance.

Comment: Well, I definitely don't like to have to repeat by subqueries...it just seems odd to do that. Having said that, I just assumed that they were bad because...that's what...I've...read...everywhere....

Comment: Can you perhaps explain why it'll be faster in this instance / and not others?

Comment: For a subquery, using `IN` or `EXISTS` calculates the subquery once and short circuits.  For a `LEFT JOIN` you return the whole result set in the `JOIN`ed table then filter out.  `IN` can be slower if you use specific values or a set, but for a subquery the exec plan is normally the same as as `EXISTS` subquery, which short circuits.

Comment: @Swati - it also short circuits, but `NOT IN` can be dangerous because of how it handles `NULL`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without subqueries:

```
SELECT ItemID
  FROM TableA
INTERSECT 
SELECT b.ItemID
  FROM TableB AS b
       LEFT OUTER JOIN TableA AS a
          ON b.ParentID = a.ItemID
 WHERE a.ItemID IS NULL;
```

...but is your fear of subqueries rational? :) I'd find this equivalent query easier to read and understand:

```
SELECT ItemID
  FROM TableA
INTERSECT 
SELECT ItemID
  FROM TableB
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (
                   SELECT * 
                     FROM TableA AS a
                    WHERE a.ItemID = TableB.ParentID
                  );
```

Comment: Thanks :) It is an irrational fear, I think :)

Comment: The one fear I have with `in (subquery)` is the limitation of the number of results you can have in the `in` clause.  In fact I recently ran into that error stating I could only have a max of 2100 id's in my `in` clause on sql server 2008 r2 express.

Comment: @goku_da_master: sounds like you are not actually using `IN ( <table expression, could be a subquery> )` but rather `IN (<comma separated list>)` or perhaps `IN (<table constructor>)` -- every parser has its limits!

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at [Select all rows from one table that don't exist in another table](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DataDesign/the-ten-most-asked-sql-server-questions--1#4) to see 5 different ways to do this kind of query by using

NOT IN
NOT EXISTS
LEFT and RIGHT JOIN
OUTER APPLY (2005+)
EXCEPT (2005+)

Here is a script that you can run

```
CREATE TABLE #TableA( ItemId int)

INSERT #TableA values(1)
INSERT #TableA values(2)
INSERT #TableA values(3) 
INSERT #TableA values(4)
INSERT #TableA values(5)
INSERT #TableA values(6) 


CREATE TABLE #TableB( ItemId int, ParentID int)
INSERT #TableB values(1,1)
INSERT #TableB values(2,2)
INSERT #TableB values(4,3)
INSERT #TableB values(5,4)
```

this will do it for parent

```
SELECT a.ItemID
FROM #TableA a
LEFT JOIN #TableB b ON a.ItemId = b.ParentID
WHERE b.ItemID IS NULL

SELECT a.ItemID
FROM #TableA a
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM #TableB b WHERE a.ItemId = b.ParentID)
```

Output

```
ItemID
5
6
```

Comment: That gives me a nullset. ALL items have parents, so I am not sure if it'll ever be null.

Comment: None of those work for me. I don't believe that the linked question applies - I DO need records which exist in both tables BUT where the ParentID (in TableB) is not an ItemID in TableA

Comment: That's an invalid data set for me. ALL the ItemIDs in Table A exist in Table B as ItemIDs as well. (Table A is a subset of Table B, if you will). TableB also stores ParentIDs, all of which are also valid ItemIDs.

Comment: Updated, I guess I misunderstood

Comment: For the first query, I had to modify it to SELECT DISTINCT and do WHERE b.ItemID IS NOT NULL - but that worked, thanks

Comment: FYI, I wanted the 'opposite' result of what you posted (which I why Ihad to do NOT NULL)

Comment: -1 Using the OP's data, your queries do not yield the OP's Desired Result.

Answer (score 0):

You can use outer joins. Something like this:

```
SELECT a.ItemID
FROM TableA a
INNER JOIN TableB b ON a.ItemId = b.ItemID
LEFT JOIN TableB parentB on a.ItemID = parentB.ParentID 
WHERE parentB.ParentID IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Tables A and B seem to store a tree structure. I'd interpret table A as "Nodes" (storing elements of the tree) and Table B as "Edges" (linking a node to it's parent). The inner join variant is very elegant since it covers all cases of "no edge to parent", "edge to PrantID null" and "edge to non existant parent" at once.
cheers